# WordPress: loop with array value not returning posts

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I'm having problem with WordPress's loop while trying to filter out custom posts. The very basic version of the loop works just fine:

```
                $args = array(  
                    'post_type' => 'house',
                    'orderby' => 'title',
                    'order' => 'ASC',
                    'posts_per_page' => -1, 
                );
```

This code returns all the posts as it should. Now if I try to filter the posts (depending on user selections stored in `$types` array) I get nothing:

```
                   $args = array(  
                        'post_type' => 'house',
                        'orderby' => 'title',
                        'order' => 'ASC',
                        'posts_per_page' => -1, 
                        'meta_query' => array(
                            array(
                                'key' => 'investment_type',
                                'value' => $types,
                                'compare' => 'IN'
                            )
                        ),
                    );
```

`$types` is an array and 'type' is an ACF checkbox field that all 'house" posts use. Field names, post type names etc. are all correct and I've checked them dozens of times already, so that shouldn't be an issue.

`print_r` of `$types` returns the following (sorry the values are in Finnish):

```
Array ( [0] => Liiketilat [1] => Päivittäistavarakauppa [2] => Päiväkoti )
```

`var` dump of `$args` returns this:

```
array(5) { ["post_type"]=> string(5) "house" ["orderby"]=> string(5) "title" ["order"]=> string(3) "ASC" ["posts_per_page"]=> int(-1) ["meta_query"]=> array(1) { [0]=> array(3) { ["key"]=> string(16) "investment_type" ["value"]=> array(3) { [0]=> string(10) "Liiketilat" [1]=> string(24) "Päivittäistavarakauppa" [2]=> string(11) "Päiväkoti" } ["compare"]=> string(2) "IN" } } }
```

And the ACF checkbox field of `investment_type` has the following values, assigned to correct house posts (which have been published):

```
Retail
Yhteiskuntakiinteistöt
Logistiikka ja varastot
Liiketilat
Päivittäistavarakauppa
Päiväkoti
```

What could be the issue here? The query works with radio button ACF fields and returns posts that it should, but checkbox field (array) is giving me a headache.

Thanks for the help!